# How to make a UITableView with a database on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, uitableview

I want to display data into sections that I get from database. My objective is to display data depending on date of creation (date is an attribute of my object), so the header must be the date of creation. Any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to have other people do work for you. Provide more details and a more specific question and show that you've made an effort to do this on your own. Code samples, links, and images are always good.

Answer (score 2):

This can help you get started:

- [iOSMadeSimple UITableView Tutorial](http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2012/10/adding-uitableview-tutorial.html)
- [iOSDevNotes UITableView Tutorial](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/10/uitableview-tutorial/)
- [AppCoda UITableView Tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/)
- [TechPro UITableView Tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1026/how-to-create-and-populate-a-uitableview)

Ohh, How can I forget to mention [UITableView Class Refernce](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/)

And always remember, Don't start seeking help without doing **Anything** on your own.

At least, do some research before posting a question here. I hope you'll learn that quicker.